# Inline Editing works, but only for some fields? Can't inline edit the Stage field.

Tags: opportunity, inline, edit

My users can inline edit most fields in an Opportunities view. However they cannot edit the standard Stage field.

[This SF help doc covers reasons why you can't inline edit](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003911), but the problem is, I CAN inline edit, just not that specific field.

Comment: Inline edit in List View or on Opportunity Detail page? See http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opportunities
All fields are editable, except the following fields are only editable on detail pages (not on list views):

1. Amount
2. **Stage**
3. Forecast Category
4. Quantity

Like you can see, the Stage is editable on the detail pages only.

[Guidelines for Editing Records with the Inline Editor](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_inline_editing.htm&language=en_US)